# How do I make <div> stretch exactly do the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I want this  to reach exactly the bottom of the screen, however I have a header, so if I set height: 100%;, it is too big, and the page is scrollable. Obviously the same with 100vh. And I don't want to calculate it manually, because of responsiveness. My CSS may look crappy, because I tried literally everything I could think of.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #2e3e56;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
}

/*header*/
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2e3e56;
    color: #d0cbc5;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding: 0.3% 0% 0.3% 0%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#header table{
    width: 100%;
}

#hnametd p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#hnametd h1{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#hlogotd{
    width: 18%;
    padding: 0;
}

#hlogo{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*-------*/

/*hr-area*/
hr{
    height: 10px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dblue{
    background-color: #156390;
}

.lblue{
    background-color: #7296ab;
}

.gray{
    background-color: #d0cbc5;
}

.hrbottom{
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*-------*/

#wrapper{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2e3e56;
    padding-right: 3.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*sibebar*/
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.955rem;
    padding: 2.2% 0 2.2% 2.2%;
    max-width: 21%;
}

#sidebar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.con-li{
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

#sidebar h2{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #d0cbc5;
}

#sidebar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#sidebar a:hover{
    color: #7296ab;
}
/*----*/

/*main*/
#main{
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    min-height: 100vh;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 77.5%;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.625rem;
}

#main h1{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#main p{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="hlogotd"><img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo" id="hlogo"></td>
                <td id="hnametd">
                    <h1>Header heading</h1>
                    <p>Header placeholder text.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <hr class="dblue">
    <hr class="lblue">
    <hr class="gray">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Sidebar heading</h2>
            <p>Some placeholder text.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <hr class="dblue">
            <p>Some placeholder text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="gray hrbottom">
    <hr class="lblue hrbottom">
    <hr class="dblue hrbottom">
```

Comment: You should probably use Grid or Flexbox if possible depending on what browsers you are targeting. Alternatives include making the header and footer fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below uses flexbox. I avoided changing your HTML by making the body a flex container (but it could be another parent element - it too would need to be 100% height).

First, my changes, just to highlight them:

```
/* flex container - happens to be body here */
body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

html, body{
    height: 100vh;
}

#wrapper{
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

Full CSS based on your original can be found here: https://codepen.io/andrew1357/pen/rNmwGpz?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of doing this. One way would be to calculate the minimum height, by subtracting everything else (when added up). In this case, your header and those 6 <hr> tags add up to 247px. You can also include support for different browsers. You can also use <header> tags instead of a div.

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body{
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    color: #2e3e56;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    width: 65%;
    margin: auto;
}

/*header*/
#header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2e3e56;
    color: #d0cbc5;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding: 0.3% 0% 0.3% 0%;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#header table{
    width: 100%;
}

#hnametd p{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#hnametd h1{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#hlogotd{
    width: 18%;
    padding: 0;
}

#hlogo{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
/*-------*/

/*hr-area*/
hr{
    height: 10px;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.dblue{
    background-color: #156390;
}

.lblue{
    background-color: #7296ab;
}

.gray{
    background-color: #d0cbc5;
}

.hrbottom{
    height: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
/*-------*/

#wrapper{
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2e3e56;
    padding-right: 3.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*sibebar*/
#sidebar{
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.955rem;
    padding: 2.2% 0 2.2% 2.2%;
    max-width: 21%;
}

#sidebar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}

.con-li{
    margin: 1em 0 1em 0;
}

#sidebar h2{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #d0cbc5;
}

#sidebar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#sidebar a:hover{
    color: #7296ab;
}
/*----*/

/*main*/
#main{
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 247px);
    height: -o-calc(100% - 247px); /* opera */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 247px); /* google, safari */
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 247px); /* firefox */
    height: 100%;
    width: 77.5%;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.625rem;
}

#main h1{
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#main p{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>
<header id="header">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="hlogotd"><img src="logo.svg" alt="Logo" id="hlogo"></td>
                <td id="hnametd">
                    <h1>Header heading</h1>
                    <p>Header placeholder text.</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>
    <hr class="dblue">
    <hr class="lblue">
    <hr class="gray">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <h2>Sidebar heading</h2>
            <p>Some placeholder text.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            <hr class="dblue">
            <p>Some placeholder text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="gray hrbottom">
    <hr class="lblue hrbottom">
    <hr class="dblue hrbottom">
</html>
```